# Try catch block outside the main() scope

Tags: c++, try-catch

I am able to compile and run this. How it is possible to write a try-catch block outside the main scope, seems to defy my logic? Any term to describe this behavior?

```
int main() try
{

}

catch(...){}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a [Function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block)

> A function-try-block associates a sequence of catch clauses with the
>   entire function body, and with the member initializer list (if used in
>   a constructor) as well. Every exception thrown from any statement in
>   the function body, or (for constructors) from any member or base
>   constructor, or (for destructors) from any member or base destructor,
>   transfers control to the handler-sequence the same way an exception
>   thrown in a regular try block would.